# PHP, Get event from table in month interval by day/month/year

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a function to getting event in month interval, where I sending a day, month and year to a function. And I need this... When I post to a function a date 30.5.2015 and event in db will be on 31.4.2015 then I need to show event on that 30.5.2015 day. Now it works that event I see on every day.... Function looks like bellow....

```
function loadAllDayEventsIntervalMonthly($array) {
    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT * from `kalendar_user_events` where `interval`='3' and `uid`='" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "' and `allDay`='1'";
    foreach ($db->select($query) as $res) {

        $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $array->month, $array->year);
        $daysDb = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $res->month, $res->year);

        if ($array->day != $res->day) {
            if ($res->day > $days and $days > $daysDb) {
                echo "<input type='hidden' class='eachEventForDay' data-id='" . $res->id . "'
                 data-color='" . $res->color . "' data-name='" . $res->name . "' data-place='" . $res->place . "' 
                 data-interval='" . $res->interval . "' data-notification='" . $res->notification . "' 
                 data-day='" . $res->day . "' data-month='" . $res->month . "' data-year='" . $res->year . "' 
                 data-allDay='" . $res->allDay . "' data-time='" . $res->time . "' data-position='" . $res->position . "' 
                 data-dragable='yes' data-from='calendar' data-edit='full'>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<input type='hidden' class='eachEventForDay' data-id='" . $res->id . "'
                 data-color='" . $res->color . "' data-name='" . $res->name . "' data-place='" . $res->place . "' 
                 data-interval='" . $res->interval . "' data-notification='" . $res->notification . "' 
                 data-day='" . $res->day . "' data-month='" . $res->month . "' data-year='" . $res->year . "' 
                 data-allDay='" . $res->allDay . "' data-time='" . $res->time . "' data-position='" . $res->position . "' 
                 data-dragable='yes' data-from='calendar' data-edit='full'>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 31.4.2015 this wont come in month of april...be specific in question not getting what exactly you want to ask

Comment: I need to get Event from DB which is day 31, but if actual clicked month will have only 30 days then get to 30th day... I think that is clear when it is in month interval.

Comment: But anyway, sry this question is hard to explain

Comment: Can you put your desired output, so it would help to solve problem.

Comment: Wait a moment it will take a while becouse it is over ajax so I must do some exceptions :-D

Comment: Output is this Show date by user: 30.9.2015(30 days in month), date from db: 31.8.2015(31 days in month on created event) and I added this line `$pol = "Show date by user: ".$array->day.".".$array->month.".".$array->year."(".$days." days in month), date from db: ".$res->day.".".$res->month.".".$res->year."(".$daysDb." days in month on created event)<br />";
  `

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it.... If u interest how... there is code

```
function loadAllDayEventsIntervalMonthly($array){
        global $db;

        $query = "SELECT * from `kalendar_user_events` where `interval`='3' and `uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' and `allDay`='1'";
        foreach($db->select($query) as $res){

        $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $array->month, $array->year);
        $daysDb = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $res->month, $res->year);        


        if($array->day != $res->day){

                if($array->day < $days){

                }else{
                echo "<input type='hidden' class='eachEventForDay' data-id='".$res->id."'
                 data-color='".$res->color."' data-name='".$res->name."' data-place='".$res->place."' 
                 data-interval='".$res->interval."' data-notification='".$res->notification."' 
                 data-day='".$res->day."' data-month='".$res->month."' data-year='".$res->year."' 
                 data-allDay='".$res->allDay."' data-time='".$res->time."' data-position='".$res->position."' 
                 data-dragable='yes' data-from='calendar' data-edit='full'>";   
                }


        }else{
            echo "<input type='hidden' class='eachEventForDay' data-id='".$res->id."'
                 data-color='".$res->color."' data-name='".$res->name."' data-place='".$res->place."' 
                 data-interval='".$res->interval."' data-notification='".$res->notification."' 
                 data-day='".$res->day."' data-month='".$res->month."' data-year='".$res->year."' 
                 data-allDay='".$res->allDay."' data-time='".$res->time."' data-position='".$res->position."' 
                 data-dragable='yes' data-from='calendar' data-edit='full'>";   
        }


        }       



        }
```